# How to pass chai assertions to component using react

Tags: reactjs, testing, eval, chai

I am using the [Chai assertion library](http://chaijs.com) in order to run some trivial tests on my code. I have a react component running on the client. It needs to receive assertion statements as props. Right now i am passing Strings like `assert.isDefined(myVariable)` and just run them using `eval()`. I am not happy with the state of things. How could i pass an array of assertions using props without using eval?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `eval()` ans passing the data as a string. It works.